# Why does my i2c sensor stop responding when attaching another sensor to the bus?

Tags: arduino, i2c, gyroscope

I am experiencing a problem reading gyro(mpu6050) data with a RTC(RTC DS3231) attached to the i2c bus. Using the Arduino Pro micro 5V 16MHz.

Testing the gyro with the rtc SCL pin disconnected works fine and the gyro responds as expected, as you can see in this image:
[Oscilloscope image of the SDA pin.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9oDc.jpg)

When connecting the rtc SCL to the Arduino the gyro stops responding. [Oscillosope image of the SDA pin.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jS1Na.jpg)

I have tested this with just internal and with external pull-up resistors. Both showing the same behavior.

Comment: Can you show the source code?

Comment: do they have different I2C addresses?

Comment: Yes both have I2C addresses and running a I2C scanner also shows both are connected.

Comment: The source is just this simple example sketch: https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/MPU-6050/

Comment: You should always post your code instead of link to someone's tutorial, especially when you are combining MPU6050 code (which your URL linked to) with some code you used for RTC DS3231.

Comment: Let me rephrase what @Juraj is asking, how do you connect the Arduino to MPU-6050? The RTC DS3231 by default has an I2C address of 0x68, the MPU-6050 happened to have an I2C address of 0x69 if AD0 line on MPU-6050 breakout board is high, and I2C address of 0x68 if AD0 is low. Could that be both of your I2C are set to 0x68?